# Cut a part of two mesh intersection

Tags: mesh

i tryed and googled for hours but couldn't find a solution that works.

I want to remove the gold part as sown below, the gold mesh and the pink ones are different object

mesh 1
[image]

mesh 2
[image]

remove the intersection (red signed)
[image]

thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could join the 2 objects into one, select the hat mesh in Edit mode, go into the *Face panel > Intersect (Knife)*:

[image]

Separate the hat with <kbd>P</kbd>, select the edge loop the intersect operation has created, press <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to rip:

[image]

Remove this part:

[image]

Comment: i don't know why you use knife if you have laser eyes....‍♂️

Comment: @Chris Yet you know I lost all my superpowers because of your kryptonite  :((

Comment: not all...i saw your cup of coffee...that was pretty nice!!

Comment: Well, actually, Loïs brought me this coffee

Comment: yes, but you brought the LIGHT ;)

Comment: oh, no, God created the light, I can just move it

Comment: That’s not correct. Press Shift-A -> Light. And watch yourself creating light - out of nowhere.

Comment: wow, now the question is, did Ton Roosendaal create God

Comment: Yes…or…is he….?